# Superman/Batman/JLA continuity

Tags: dc, batman, superman, wonder-woman, justice-league

So, I've recently begun collecting comics again so that my newborn son can grow up reading the same comics I did and sharing in the same joys as I. I'm focusing mostly on the big 3: Batman, Superman, and Wonder Woman. My question is in regards to the formation of the Justice League of America.

In The Death of Superman series, particularly in Funeral For A Friend, we see Batman and Wonder Woman watching Superman die from the JLA HQ... which takes place after Superman: Panic in the Sky, which by all rights could be a precursor to the JLA's origin... but when does the actual League form? I plan on getting the Morrison run to the JLA and I was wondering how that fits in chronology with the events of Superman's death and return / Batman's Knightfall trilogy. If not, then could anybody point me in the direction of finding the origin story for the Post-Crisis JLA in relation to the events listed above?

Edit:
I am not overly concerned with any of the newer publications. I consider this time of Post Crisis to Infinite Crisis to be the heyday of DC's comics and desire to focus mainly on that. As such, I just wanna post Post-Crisis to Infinite Crisis in a somewhat logical order for my son, wife, and I to have a somewhat complete story.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Comment: DC's continuity is, frankly, broken. The events you name took place at least 3 reboots ago, though some of them have percolated into what passes for the present continuity. The current JLA was founded at the onset of the New 52, parts of which are still intact. It makes it very difficult to answer your question as asked.

Comment: Totally understand, and thank you for the quick response. I am not overly concerned with any of the newer publications. I consider this time of Post Crisis to Infinite Crisis to be the heyday of DC's comics and desire to focus mainly on that. The only series(s) I liked from the New 52 Reboot were Snyder's Batman, Rucka's WW, and Higgin's Nightwing. 

As such, I just wanna post Post-Crisis to Infinite Crisis in a somewhat logical order for my son, wife, and I to have a somewhat complete story.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I have since done so. Sorry, new to all this.

Comment: No worries, here to help.

Answer (score 5):

Secret Origins #32 and Justice League of America #9 Are the best explanation of the League's Post-Crisis origin. The main differences involve Black Canary being a member instead of Batman, Wonder Woman and Superman. The base origin story, that of the Appelaxians waging their war on Earth, is largely unchanged.

In post-crisis continuity, Superman and Wonder Woman came in much later in the history of the new post-Crisis Earth. IIRC, it's Hal Jordan as Green Lantern and Barry Allen as Flash who appeared first, which is in line with the order they were re-introduced in the Silver Age. Batman worked more under the cover of night, and only emerged as a public figure a bit later along.

Mark Waid and Brian Augustyn's miniseries *JLA Year One* is a good look at the early team in their post-Crisis continuity. Classic scene of Aquaman looking all over the headquarters for a bulb wrench at Hal Jordan's (IIRC) request is worth the price of admission.

Answer (score 2):

VBartilucci's answer covers the stories with the post-Crisis JLA origin.

I will note that, immediately post-Crisis, the League was disbanded. We saw this happen in *JUSTICE LEAGUE OF AMERICA* (1960) #258-261. However, as that was part of the pre-/during Crisis reality, we can't be sure if the events were the same or not afterwards. I believe Gypsy's involvement with the League in some form was confirmed during her appearances in *JUSTICE LEAGUE TASK FORCE*.

Whatever happened, the reformation of the League was a result of the *LEGENDS* miniseries in 1986-7, leading to the *JUSTICE LEAGUE*/*JUSTICE LEAGUE INTERNATIONAL*/*JUSTICE LEAGUE AMERICA* title. This is the one initially written by J. Marc DeMatteis and Keith Giffen; the one that crossed over into the Doomsday/Death of Superman storyline in the 90s.

Which should help some in your placement of events. The League was up and running long before "Panic in the Sky"; however, that story would appear to be happening during their "Breakdowns" storyline, which ended with a new version of the JLA and the Justice League Europe team (which became Justice League International at that time). So, the League was around, but not necessarily fully functional during "Panic in the Sky".

The new version of the League was pulled together by/around Superman (*JUSTICE LEAGUE AMERICA SPECTACULAR*, *JUSTICE LEAGUE AMERICA* # 61). as noted, it crossed over into the "Death od Superman" story (issues 69-70). It continued without him during the Superman replacements storylines. Ultimately, Wonder Woman got involved (around issue #77). The team got another revamp, with Wonder Woman basically in charge, after Zero Hour (which preceded issue #93), which saw the team return to a satellite HQ. That's the version of the team that was replaced by the (pre-Crisis original team) big 7 with Grant Morrison's *JLA* title.

Knightfall/Knightquest/Knightsend are roughly contemporaneous with Death of Superman and the Superman replacement storylines.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for your answers. So, in short. I need.... Justice League Year One, then Panic in the Sky, then Justice League America Spectacular, and JusticeLeague America #61, then I can do the Death of Superman, Knightfall, Return of Superman, and then Morrison's JLA?

Is that... more or less... correct?

Comment: The Spectacular would cover the "origin" of Superman's version of the League. There's lots more you could add: *LEGENDS* (return of the League, *and* the origin of the Suicide Squad); there should be trades of much of the DeMatteis/Giffen JL/I/A & JLE runs; there's the *MAN OF STEEL* trades, with John Byrne's Superman relaunch (by now, I think there are 9 of these or more, so it may cover much of his run); Wonder Woman by George Perez; Batman Years 1-3, Death in the Family, a Lonely Place of Dying (I think this is the first Tim Drake story), etc. But, yes, correct if not complete :-).